# Ajax call is only working on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I am on the main page of my application, my ajax call works just fine.

```
 $('.upvote').click(function(event) {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('downVoted');
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        var count = $(this).children().data('count');
        var altcount = $(this).siblings().children().data('count');
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'upvote/' + id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    "id": id,
                    "method": 'GET',
                    "_token": token
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                done :
                    $(this).addClass('upVoted').children().html(count +1),
                success:
                    $(this).siblings().children().html(altcount === 0 ? altcount : altcount -1)
            });

});
```

But when I am switch to a different page that has the exact same click buttons and functions as my main page, the ajax call suddenly no longer works. It will only work on my main page and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: is your ajax script included in different pages?

Comment: anything useful in the browser developer tools console? do you have an element in the page with class including `upvote`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Laravel and the ajax script is in my layout which is included in all the pages of my application.

Comment: The classes and controls are all the exact same on all my pages, they all just have different collections of data on them.

Comment: I doubt this works (properly) anywhere, since `done:` and `success:` expect functions, not result of calling a function

Comment: It works just fine on the home page, but it only works there.

Comment: **anything useful in the browser developer tools console** (F12 on a browser near you)

Comment: The developer tools is saying 404 not found with this link
http://127.0.0.1:8000/vote/upvote/4?id=4&method=GET

Comment: Ajax URL path is not correct, I guess. Try giving correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer just now. I had to add another '/' to each of my urls, now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dashBoardSearchBar").on("keyup", function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        var url = window.location.origin + "/search"; // Construct the URL

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            data: { search: query },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#searchResultsContainer").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

use this var url = window.location.origin + "/search"; for url